# Single quotes on parameters in a LESS mixin

Tags: internet-explorer, css, less, gradient

I'm trying to do this in LESS (using the JS version):-

```
.gradient-horizontal (@from, @to, @fallback)
{    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(@from), to(@to)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  @from,  @to); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    filter:      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='@from', endColorstr='@to'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='@from', endColorstr='@to')"; /* IE8 */
}
```

It seems to work fine for Firefox and Chrome, and if I replace the @from and @to in the IE lines with literal colours it works, but as you see it above it looks like the @from and @to are being passed through unmodified when surrounded by single quotes. However, the IE code will not work without them.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:-

```
.gradient-horizontal (@from, @to, @fallback)
{   

    background: @fallback; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(@from), to(@to)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  @from,  @to); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

    filter:  ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='@{from}', endColorstr='@{to}')"; /* IE6 & IE7 */
    -ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='@{from}', endColorstr='@{to}')"; /* IE8 */
}
```